# Transfert data from modal to parent page

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a button to open an external modal in a HTML page. In this modal I have some images listed. When I click on a image I would like a send to my parent page an info.

How can I do that ?

My form:

```
<button class="img-change">Open my modal</button>
<form>
  <input type="text">
</form>
<div class="modal fade" id="showLibraryFiles"></div>
```

Open my modal:

```
$('.img-change').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#showLibraryFiles').load('listFiles.php');
    $('#showLibraryFiles').modal('show');
});
```

My modal:

```
...
// On click on this image:
// 1: close modal
// 2: populate the input file with the src
<img src="image.png">
...
```

Comment: you have duplicate IDs for your button and your modal

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.. However, im not quite sure what you mean by "populate the input file with the src"

```
$('.img-change').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#showLibraryFiles').load('listFiles.php');
    $('#showLibraryFiles').modal('show');
    $('#showLibraryFiles img').click(function(){
         $('#showLibraryFiles').modal('hide');
         var src = $(this).attr('src');
         $('input').val(src);//populate the input file with the src
    });
});
```